# Simplify not working for a real part of a complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

When I try to get the real part of a term, for example:

$\qquad \Re\left(\frac{e^{-i k} \left(2 k^2+\pi ^2 \left(-1+e^{i k}\right)\right)}{\pi ^2-k^2}\right)$

*Mathematica* will output the same thing again. Also when I use `FullSimplify[Re[%]]` it will give me not a simplified term. Why?
As one can easily see, the real part of it is:

$\qquad \frac{\pi ^2-\left(\pi ^2-2 k^2\right) \cos (k)}{\pi ^2-k^2}$

So, there is indeed a simplification. Why am I not getting it?

Comment: FullSimplify[Re[ComplexExpand[%]]] - but the reason for the behavior is that Mathematica does not assume that `k` is real-valued

Comment: What we mean by Simple is different for different people. Programmatically speaking, Simplify typically looks for an expression which has the least number of "leaves" in it. You may want to consider options for Simplify such as ExcludedForms and Assumptions

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @JasonB when I use our expression it works, thank you! But also when I tell Mathematice that k is real, it will not simplify it by only using Simplify[$, Assumptions -> k e Reals]

Comment: Just: `Simplify@ComplexExpand@Re[expr]` where `expr = Exp[-I k] (2 k^2 + Pi^2 (-1 + Exp[I k]))/(Pi^2 - k^2)` (or combine the two). No need for `FullSimplify` here. The `ComplexExpand[Re[...]]` is a standard way to do such things, as it treats all symbolic variables as real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, Sometimes `Re` can stay unevaluated for numeric arguments, for example

```
Simplify @ Re[Sqrt[1 + I]]
(* yields Re[Sqrt[1 + I]] *)
```

So you may need to add FunctionalExpand to simplify it:

```
FunctionExpand @ %
(* yields Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[2]]/2^(3/4) *)
```

So for your example, it would be:

```
ComplexExpand[Re[(\[Pi]^2 - (\[Pi]^2 - 2 k^2) Cos[k])/(\[Pi]^2 - k^2)], 
 k \[Element] Complexes]
```

depending on your assumptions. Hope that helps!